# Display database data to a datatable using service builder

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, datatable, liferay

Currently i am following liferay tutorial and is using their way of processing database with service builder. [>service builder steps here<](https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/what-is-service-builder-0)

In their tutorial, they were using container to display the database result into a table as shown below:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container
    total="<%= GuestbookLocalServiceUtil.getGuestbooksCount(scopeGroupId) %>">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= GuestbookLocalServiceUtil.getGuestbooks(scopeGroupId, 
            searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Guestbook" modelVar="guestbook">
<tr>
       <td> <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="name" /></td>
       <td> <liferay-ui:search-container-column-status property="status" /></td>

       <td> <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
            align="right" 
            path="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" /></td>
</tr>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

However, now i need to use Hibernate to process the database in service builder and then using jquery datatables to display them.

**My question is: Is the service builder already using hibernate? and how can i integrate them with datatables to display the data?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your question properly, though i trying to answer you correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Liferay already using hibernate internally and you use same approach via service builder. And if you wish to display using jQuery data-table then you can add methods/functions in liferay service-impl class as per your requirement and use them to fetch the results, you can use these results data to display how ever you want into the jsp.

Comment: yes i have heard that liferay uses hibernate directly..however from the example that i follow, while configuring that database using service builder, i dont recall myself typing 'hibernate' anywhere thats why i was suspecting if they actually used it. Secondly, yes i was trying to fetch and display the result in a datatable but i do not know how to switch from their container method to the conventional method..any example is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a step by step guide to create a service & portlet please follow it. https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/90327066

Comment: i have already completed the services using liferay tutorial..i just dont know if it is hibernate AND the way to retrieve the data from database using the service completed

Comment: it's uses hibernate you need to use XXXUtil class to access your services in portlet class.

Comment: perhaps my question is phrased wrongly...how do i display the database data on a datatable in a lets say view.jsp file? my previous method was using container but apparently containers cant work with datatables

Comment: For example, <% List<Entity> list = XXXUtil.getContacts(-1,-1) %> and use this list to display data in datatable traverse through for loop. it's very simple.

Comment: Just trying my luck here..originally using container method you can directly reference a path using path="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" using container which would display a button in a column. Any idea how to carry it out on a datatable ?

Comment: Just add the html button and add link action/render url whichever is required.

Comment: the icon menu supposedly already written inside my actions.jsp and i need to link it..any example you can think of?

Comment: <div class="buttons">
                <portlet:actionURL name="<%=ACTION_ADD_TO_BASKET%>" var="addToBasketURL">
                    <portlet:param name="<%=PARAM_PRODUCT_ID%>" value="${product.id}"/>
                </portlet:actionURL>
                <input type="button" onclick="location.href = '${addToBasketURL}'" value="<f:message key="ss-msg-buy"/>"/>
            </div> add/replace parameters according your need.

Comment: This is my current implementation for the datatable: https://pastebin.com/rLRdQr8a
how do i integrate it? the codes that you are quoting are very different from my example.

Comment: it's very simple, consider you want to delete the book with below code <td> 
        <portlet:actionURL name="<%=DELETE_BOOK%>" var="deleteBookUrl">
                <portlet:param name="bookId" value="${book.id}"/>
         </portlet:actionURL>
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='${deleteBookUrl}'" value="Delete"/>

</td>

Comment: the buttons and functions of editing and deleting are already inside a jsp page named guestbook_actions.jsp.. i just need to reference to the jsp page to display the buttons https://pastebin.com/Ux3tHzaA

Comment: I am not sure if you can still include jsp page to get the row and add the actions from there. This is the approach i know with datatable.